# Remove 'file locked for editing' attribute from MS Word/ Excel documents

Tags: microsoft-excel, command-line, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, smb

In the same essence as this question [Excel file locked for editing](https://superuser.com/questions/491020/how-do-i-prevent-excel-from-locking-files-by-default). Is there a command I can type to remove the lock flag? for example:

```
attrib -R example.docx
```

-- The story --

In our office we share docx and xlsx via a NAS server. Am the person assigned who goes through these documents and have them 'processed'. Other team members should only be reading the file. Sometimes asking them to close the document would release the lock but in some cases it won't, either network problem or software problem. It's quite annoying, as I'd have to open the word doc, save it as a new copy, open the NAS control panel and delete the old file, then rename the duplicated copy...

Comment: I also have the same problem where I open a workbook at work and successfully make changes, close it, and then try to open it again - It opens in read only mode complaining it is locked by another user (???). Often I find that if I close and reopen a second time the mysterious lock is gone and I have write access.