# How to prevent Excel from modifying the file on exit?

Tags: microsoft-excel, version-control

Whenever I open an Excel file and then close it without changing anything, the Excel would modify the file without asking a permission or giving any kind of warning. It modifies just 4 bytes at offset 0x046C, and I suspect this might be just the hard-coded last-modified time or something like that.

The problem is that this really screws up the versioning control system, since the file's MD5 sum changes.

Is there any way to stop Excel from doing this? As far as I can see there are no links of formulas or any other dynamic elements in the file.

Comment: I just tested using winmd5, and a blank excel file - opening and closing (without saving or any editing) returns the same MD5 hash. File created - opened on Excel 2013. What version of excel do you use?

Comment: @Darius Excel 2010. The file changes even if I open it in protected view and do not allow editing.

Comment: Are you talking about a file where you open it and then decide whether or not to modify it? Or are you talking about a file that you will never (or very rarely) modify? In the second case, try setting the read-only attribute, or setting permissions so you don’t have permission to write to the file. . . . Also, have you checked your system for malware?

Comment: Are there any Excel add-ins active that might do that?

Comment: No addins (except a Bluetooth plugin, which isn't supposed to do anything to a file); and the antivirus protection is active, so presumably no malware.

Comment: Have you tried making the file read-only?

Comment: I wonder whether [opening them read-only](http://superuser.com/a/491191/144771) will avoid this problem. Will probably know in a while and try to remember to report back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem, and after several hours reading through several forums and pages I found the root cause of the problem and solution, so I’ll be copy&pasting my answer on the forums I read.

There seems to be an issue with excel files, in particular Excel 2003 xls files, whenever they get opened in Excel, even if they don't get changed and don't get saved, Excel automatically updates some of the file's metadata, such as the "Document Properties and Personal Information" and "Last Accessed Statistics", therefore the file every time it gets opened changes a little bit, and this makes that the MD5 changes also.

**Solution:**

One way to avoid this problem is to remove *document properties and personal information*.

To remove the hidden data and personal information from Office documents, in [Excel 2007](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/remove-hidden-data-and-personal-information-from-office-documents-HA010037593.aspx) and for [Excel 2013/2010](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/starter-help/remove-hidden-data-and-personal-information-by-inspecting-workbooks-HA010354331.aspx).

Other way to avoid this would be to use `.xlsx` files. I have been trying to replicate this behavior in `.xlsx` files, but it seems to only happen on `.xls` (2003) files.

Comment: I cleaned up your answer a bit, but it's still VLQ; can you copy the information on the links into your answer, and put the links just as your cited source? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To avoid any possibility of changing any file meta-data, copy the file and open the copy.